# SassError: There is no module with the namespace "mat" (Angular Material Theming)

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

Ich have one _theme.scss file...

```
// _theme.scss
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@include mat.core();
// Import theming functions
@import "@angular/material/theming";

$primary-palette: (
  50: #f6e0e6,
  100: #e9b3c2,
  200: #db8099,
...
```

...and one styles.scss file. In my styles.scss, I import the _theme.scss:

```
// styles.scss
@import "theme";
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($typography);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
.dark-theme {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error from styles.scss stating mat is not defined. Which makes no sense to me because I already imported mat in _themes.scss:

```
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "mat"
```

[image: Screenshot of the error in the console]

Answer (score -1):

You need to `@use` the Material styles every time you want to use their functionality. Also I would recommend you to get rid of any `@import` statement and fully switch to `@use`.

```scss
// styles.scss
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "theme";

@include mat.typography-hierarchy(theme.$typography);
@include mat.all-component-themes(theme.$theme);
.dark-theme {
  @include mat.all-component-themes(theme.$dark-theme);
}
```